# Navigating to a next page after documentCompleted in webbrowser

Tags: c#

I'm new on web scraping and I would like to get an "id" and i want webbrowser to navigate next page using this "id" and do what i want to do. For example;

```
Go to https://www.example.com/
then get "id"
navigate https://www.example.com/id
then get title name
Go to https://www.example.com/
then get "second id"
navigate https://www.example.com/id
then get title name
...
```

How can i achieve this on c#?

note: this web site has "Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol(https)"

EDIT: DocumentCompleted firing twice when url navigating to www.example.com/id

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            WB = new WebBrowser();
            WB.AllowNavigation = true;
            WB.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            WB.Navigate("https://www.example.com/page");
            WB.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WB_DocumentCompleted);
            while (completed)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

static async void WB_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = WB.Document;

            var docy = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            docy.Load(new StringReader(WB.Document.Body.InnerHtml));

            HtmlElementCollection divs = doc.GetElementsByTagName("td");

            if (WB.Url.ToString().IndexOf("page") > -1)
            {     
                HtmlNodeCollection prens = docy.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//*[@id='mid']//dıv//dıv//table//tbody//tr//td//a");
                for (int i = 0; i < prens.Count; i++)
                {
                    HtmlNode nodes= docy.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='mid']//dıv[6]//dıv//table[2]//tbody//tr[" + satir + "]//td[2]//a");

                    HtmlNode links = nodes;
                    if (links != null)
                    {
                        hrefValue = links.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                        string[] gelenevent = hrefValue .Split('.');
                        eventid = gelenevent[0].Remove(0, 1);

                        satir++;
                        while (WB.IsBusy)
                            Application.DoEvents();
                        for (int y = 0; y < 500; y++)
                            if (WB.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                                await Task.Delay(5000);
                                Thread.Sleep(10);
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        WB.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.example.com/" + eventid + ".html"));

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (WB.Url.ToString().IndexOf(eventid) > -1)
                {
                    var node = docy.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='mid']//dıv[6]//dıv//table[4]//tbody//tr[2]//td[1]");

                while (WB.IsBusy)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                    if (WB.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                Application.DoEvents();

                    WB.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.example.com/page"));

                }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to be more specific as to the tool you are using and what happens when you follow the steps you've outlined.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm editing now @ScottyB

Comment: This is a web scraping project.  You need to get the element of the of the control that changes the page and click the control.  On some webpages you can browse to a URL and includes the page number in URL.  Check the URL and see if it changes when you move between pages.

Comment: @ScottyB added project.

Comment: @jdweng there is no id to invoke for clicking.

Comment: There may not be an attribute "id" against the control object, but there is usually another way of getting the html element with the next page control.  I've written a lot of scraping projects and always found a way of getting the  control.  Using the tag or the tag of a parent.

Comment: @jdweng i am going to look at it. Thanks your help